# V4L2 video capture on android

Tags: android, linux, android-camera, video-capture, v4l2

I'm trying to run the video capture example code [here](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html) on a Samsung Galaxy S3.
At first I encountered several errors in many of the `VIDIOC` operations (for example `S_FMT` or `STREAMON`) which I could solve by:

1. Looking at kmsg and tracing the kernel driver code to guess what went wrong.
2. Add missing operations or fix some configurations in the example code. 
   Comparing the kmsg log from running the example code with that from launching the native camera app helped a lot.. (since the latter we are sure it works)

Now I've come to this.. All ioctls finish succesfully, but I'm getting 0 data.. `v4l2_buffer->bytesused` is always 0.

I got desperate so I added printk logs in every function in *fimc_v4l2.c* and *fimc_capture.c* (FIMC is Samsung's V4L2 driver) and this is all I'm seeing when using the **camera app**: (I'm only pasting the part after returning from `STREAMON`)

> @@@ fimc_dqbuf # bytesused=0 length=0
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture start # bytesused=0 length=0
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture # list empty
>  
>  fimc_irq_cap[0], fimc0, cnt[0]
>  fimc_irq_cap[0] SKIPPED
>  fimc_irq_cap[1], fimc0,
>   cnt[1]
>  
>  @@@ fimc_dqbuf # bytesused=0 **length=65545**
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture start # bytesused=0 length=65545
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture # list not empty
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture # length=65545
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture end # length=65545, bytesused=0
>  
>  @@@ fimc_qbuf # bytesused=0 length=0
>   ### fimc_qbuf_capture start
>   ### fimc_qbuf_capture # buf state ok
>   ### fimc_qbuf_capture # index=0
>   ### fimc_qbuf_capture end
>  @@@ fimc_dqbuf # **bytesused=3225703951** length=0
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture start # bytesused=3225703951 length=0
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture # list empty
>  
>  fimc_irq_cap[2], fimc0, cnt[2]
>  
>  @@@ fimc_dqbuf # bytesused=3225703951 length=65545
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture start # bytesused=3225703951 length=65545
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture # list not empty
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture # length=65545
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture end # length=65545, bytesused=3225703951
>  
>  @@@ fimc_qbuf # bytesused=0 length=0
>   ### fimc_qbuf_capture start
>   ### fimc_qbuf_capture # buf state ok
>   ### fimc_qbuf_capture # index=1
>   ### fimc_qbuf_capture end
>  ...

I separated the log into blocks: it's basically a `DQBUF(empty) -> IRQ -> DQBUF -> QBUF` loop. I marked in bold where `b->lenght` and `b->bytesused` first get their nonzero values.
I've modified the **v4l2 example** code to simulate this exact flow.. 
But as you can see I only get 0 for `b->lenght` and `b->bytesused`:

> @@@ fimc_dqbuf # bytesused=0 length=0
>  ### fimc_dqbuf_capture
>   start # bytesused=0 length=0
>  ### fimc_dqbuf_capture # list
>   empty
>  
>  fimc_irq_cap[0], fimc0, cnt[0]
>  fimc_irq_cap[0]
>   SKIPPED
>  fimc_irq_cap[1], fimc0, cnt[1]
>  
>  @@@ fimc_dqbuf #
>   bytesused=0 **length=0**
>  ### fimc_dqbuf_capture start #
>   bytesused=0 length=0
>  ### fimc_dqbuf_capture # list not empty
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture # length=0
>  ### fimc_dqbuf_capture end #
>   length=0, bytesused=0
>  
>  @@@ fimc_qbuf # bytesused=0
>   length=0
>  ### fimc_qbuf_capture start
>  ### fimc_qbuf_capture #
>   buf state ok
>  ### fimc_qbuf_capture # index=0
>  ###
>   fimc_qbuf_capture end
>  
>   @@@ fimc_dqbuf # **bytesused=0**
>   length=0
>  ### fimc_dqbuf_capture start # bytesused=0 length=0
>   ### fimc_dqbuf_capture # list empty
>  
>  fimc_irq_cap[2], fimc0,
>   cnt[2]
>  
>  @@@ fimc_dqbuf # bytesused=0 length=0
>  ###
>   fimc_dqbuf_capture start # bytesused=0 length=0
>  ###
>   fimc_dqbuf_capture # list not empty
>  ### fimc_dqbuf_capture #
>   length=0
>  ### fimc_dqbuf_capture end # length=0, bytesused=0
>   
>  @@@ fimc_qbuf # bytesused=0 length=0
>  ### fimc_qbuf_capture
>   start
>  ### fimc_qbuf_capture # buf state ok
>  ###
>   fimc_qbuf_capture # index=1
>  ### fimc_qbuf_capture end
>  ...

I've tried using *grep* inside the kernel driver source code to find when could `bytesused` have been assigned but couldn't find the correct location.
Does anyone have ideas? I'd be deeply grateful

### Edit

When I use `strlen()` on the pointer of my `mmap`ped buffer, it actually returns a reasonable value. The returned size changes according to where I'm pointing the camera to (it's 1 or really small when I cover the lenses with my hand, and around 10 thousand when it's bright; it also keeps changing when I'm moving the camera). I'm guessing this indicates that I'm actually getting the frames. 
But I still can't figure out why `bytesused` is always 0.